# Roland Cube 60 (Bass) PWR Amp smoking!

Tags: amplifier

My Roland Cube 60 Bass went up in smoke the other day. (after about 30 years of reliable service.) No blown fuses. Hmm. Opened it up and found that a 1/2W resistor was burned up. Similar issue here:

[Repairing/understanding this guitar amp master stage](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/181901/repairing-understanding-this-guitar-amp-master-stage)

And this schematic is the same (except for ref designators)

[image: schematic]

It's the 330 Ohm on the collector of Q10 (PNP driver).
All parts and continuity are all OK so far. (Q's, R's, C's, D's)
Was thinking that the connector to output Q13 was open. Guess not
but I may have moved something during board removal.
Power Q actually OPEN? BE junction tests OK (diode drop).

Any other ideas? (voltage on that 1/2W 330 Ohm jumps to about 30Vdc with an input! otherwise very low)

Comment: perhaps Q12 is shorted

Comment: only R54 smoked?  If replaced and you get 30V across R54 then Q13 would be smoked  open

Comment: Q12 is fine. In fact the amp still works but I think only Q12 is driving the speaker. And yes, replaced R54. When input applied, I get 20-30V across it! (say 1W on a 1/2W resistor) I also think Q13 is open. Will use a Q tester today. Parts ordered.

Comment: FOUND IT! There was an open trace from -44Vdc to (what looks like) R58... the 0.3 Ohm power resistor. Made me wonder why BUT it looks corroded right about in the middle. (I think I spilled a beer on this thing years ago!) Looks OK on the bench. Need to get a speaker on it and test it out.

Answer (score 2):

Open trace to 0.3 Ohm resistor to Q13 emitter! Looks fixed.